# Second addActionListener in the class not opening new window

Tags: java, swing

So I've been playing around with GUIs and created a relatively nice welcome-frame for my user.
Said frame has two text options, where each text option should, in theory, open a new window.

One of the text frames does exactly what it's suppose to, opens a new window, as desired, the other, however, does not.

The following is my code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Frame1Welcome extends JFrame {

private JLabel intro1 = new JLabel(
        "Welcome to Twitter Farmer.");
private JLabel intro2 = new JLabel(
        "In order to start farming up those tweets, first decide if you want to farm for a specific amount of time, or farm a certain amount of tweets.");
private JLabel intro3 = new JLabel(
        "By specifying the amount of time you wish to farm for, Twitter Farmer will gather as many tweets as it can in said time.");
private JLabel intro4 = new JLabel(
        "If you know how many you want however, Twitter Farmer will instead gather up the exact desired amount.");
private JLabel intro5 = new JLabel(
        "Please enter the time in seconds, or the amount of tweets as whole number, and press the 'ENTER'-key.");

private JLabel tweets = new JLabel("Tweets:");
private JLabel time = new JLabel("Time:");

private JTextField twitterText = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField timeText = new JTextField(10);

private String inputText; // REMOVE ME

public Frame1Welcome(String title) {
    super(title);

    launchGUI.setMyDefaults(this, 800, 300);

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);

    JPanel northernPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.add(northernPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    gbc.gridy = 0;
    northernPanel.add(intro1, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    northernPanel.add(intro2, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    northernPanel.add(intro3, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    northernPanel.add(intro4, gbc);
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    northernPanel.add(intro5, gbc);

    JPanel southernPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    this.add(southernPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    southernPanel.add(tweets, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    southernPanel.add(twitterText, gbc);

    gbc.gridy = 1;

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    southernPanel.add(time, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    southernPanel.add(timeText, gbc);

    twitterText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            inputText = twitterText.getText(); // REMOVE ME
            dispose();

            System.out.println("TWEETS:" + inputText); // REMOVE ME

            try {
                new Frame3Tweets("Twitter Farmer - Tweet-farm by desired amount", Integer.parseInt(timeText.getText()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException error) {
                    //ADD INVALID NUMBER WINDOW 
                }

        }
    });

    timeText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            inputText = timeText.getText(); // REMOVE ME
            dispose();

            System.out.println("TIME:" + inputText); // REMOVE ME

            try {
            new Frame2Time("Twitter Farmer - Tweet-farm over desired time", Integer.parseInt(timeText.getText()));
            } catch (NumberFormatException error) {
                //ADD INVALID NUMBER WINDOW 
            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

Firstly, all comment are simply to remind me of things to do later in the code.

Secondly, assume that `launchGUI.setMyDefaults(this, 800, 300);`is just my method to set the size and the visibility and all that, and it works for that for other windows.

Thirdly, assume that the `new Frame2Time` and `new Frame3Tweets` are both functional.

My question is thus:

Why does `timeText.addActionListener` create a new window, and `twitterText.addActionListener` does not?

I've tried to have `twitterText.addActionListener` make other windows too after a number has been given by the user, without any such window popping up.

Could anyone show me what I've done wrong, and preferably, how to fix it?

Comment: That's a bad practice to leave `catch` blocks empty. You're probably getting an *exception* but you don't know you are, since you're catching it and do nothing with it. Not even displaying it.

Comment: Does the main frame close when either field is actioned?

Comment: Ah, you know, there is no better way to learn than to teach yourself. I took your advice @MarounMaroun and added an error.printStackTrace() which gave me all the answers. I'll answer my own question in a bit! Thank you!

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

By taking Maroun Maroun's advice, and adding an `error.printStackTrace()` I was able to deduct my issue:

```
try {
   new Frame3Tweets("Twitter Farmer - Tweet-farm by desired amount", Integer.parseInt(timeText.getText()));
} catch (NumberFormatException error) {
   error.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

The method was taking `timeText.getText()` as an argument, which was empty and thus forced everything to crash and burn.

It should have been taking `tweetText.getText()` instead, which had a value.

So kids, follow Maroun Maroun's advice, and don't leave your `catch` blocks blank!